# Rails postgresql can't find the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, web-development-server

I'm really lost here, just learning to code and I've come across this issue. It was working fine in a previous app and then suddenly stopped working. I've created new apps and it's just coming up with the same issue again.

The terminal simply can't find the db (postgresql - has to be for assignment).

Any help is incredibly appreciated.

```
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ rails db:create
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'marketplace_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Users/mattj/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ sudo service postgresql start
[sudo] password for matthew:
 * Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server                                                                        [ OK ]
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ su - postgres
Password:
su: Authentication failure
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ su - postgres
Password:
su: Authentication failure
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ which postgres
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/postgres 
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ rails -v
Rails 6.1.3
matthew@DESKTOP-P54O83M:~/ca/coder-academy/projects/T2/MatthewKennedyT1A2/marketplace$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Look in the config file and see what unix_socket_directories is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Im new to coding too, but looking at the error log, this stands out

```
ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Could it be because the service running PostgreSQL DB - mostly a local apache server - is currently offline?

Awesome start by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command to check if postgres service is running on required port 5432 or not

pgrep -u postgres -fa -- -D

looks like some authentication issues in starting postgres service

Comment: It returned the following:
```
1019 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
```

Does that mean it's running on port 1019? and also, I've searched for that address and it isn't on my pc. I've even checked on 'everything' the file directory searcher

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1.3 sometime make problem with database, and when I worked with postgres, I used rails 5.2.4 btw to connect with database because I thought it is stable (do you?)

Please try rails 5.2.4 and tell us about the result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Postgres server is not running.
Try restarting the server.

1. Check if the Postgres server is running

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

2. Restart the Postgres server

```
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo service postgresql start
```